# How do I animate a line from my draw() function?

Tags: processing

I'm using Processing to create a learning experience project that allows users to join network components together. I have links using standard lines, but I want to be able to show a signal moving through the line if there is a valid connection. Think of the line as a network cable for example. Is there anyway I can animate this line?

```
  void draw(){
   pushStyle();
   stroke(0);
   line(from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y);
   popStyle();
 }
} //draw function in the 'link' file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, but your question is a little broad. You do have a particular type of animation in mind? Endless possibilities ;)

The basic way to handle something like this in processing is to increase some animation-variables every frame (or use time management - though that is beyond the basics).
Because the animation-variables (for instance position or color) are changed every frame, the animation is different every frame. It's animated.

Below I give an example of a small green line traveling over a black 'connection' line. If you read through the code I think you'll figure it out. This should be incorporated in a nice 'connection' class for ease of use on a larger scale.

```
//set coordinates for connection-line
int fromX = 100;
int toX = 600;
int fromY = 100;
int toY = 200;
//copy start coordinate for animation
int animx = fromX;
int animy = fromY;
//determine animation stepsize
int stepX = (toX-fromX)/10;
int stepY = (toY-fromY)/10;

void setup() {
  size(800, 300);
  //set framerate so animation is not to fast
  frameRate(5);
  //draw thick lines
  strokeWeight(10);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  // draw connection in black
  stroke(0);
  line(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
  //draw animation in green
  stroke(0, 255, 0);
  line(animx, animy, animx+stepX, animy+stepY);
  // step animation for next frame
  animx = animx+stepX;
  animy = animy+stepY;
  // check for reset (if the animation on the next frame is drawn outside the line)
  if (animx+stepX > toX)
  {
    animx = fromX;
  }
  if (animy+stepY > toY)
  {
    animy = fromY;
  }
}
```